# Need sql query for my table

Tags: distinct

My table description is

```
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| AutoPk      | int(4) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| sensorName  | varchar(20)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| SensorValue | double(65,2)    | NO   |     | 0.00              |                             |
| timest      | timestamp       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

Sample data is 

+----------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| AutoPk8_ | sensorName8_ | SensorVa3_8_ | timest8_            |
+----------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
|      104 | temperature  |        14.22 | 2013-09-20 09:59:35 |
|      104 | humidity     |        71.74 | 2013-09-20 09:59:35 |
|      104 | humidity     |        71.24 | 2013-09-20 09:56:42 |
|      104 | temperature  |        14.36 | 2013-09-20 09:56:41 |
|      104 | temperature  |        14.47 | 2013-09-20 09:53:47 |
|      104 | humidity     |        71.03 | 2013-09-20 09:53:47 |
|      104 | temperature  |        14.74 | 2013-09-20 09:50:54 |
|      104 | humidity     |        70.50 | 2013-09-20 09:50:54 |
|      104 | light intensi|        12    | 2013-09-20 09:49:00 |       
|      104 | temperature  |        15.28 | 2013-09-20 09:48:00 |
|      104 | humidity     |        69.60 | 2013-09-20 09:48:00 |
+----------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Now i need a query to find the latest record based on sensorName . Latest record here means the latest time record.

for the above i/p output should be

```
 104 | temperature  |        14.22 | 2013-09-20 09:59:35
 104 | humidity     |        71.74 | 2013-09-20 09:59:35 
 104 | light intensi|        12    | 2013-09-20 09:49:00
```

Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simply,

```
SELECT
  MyTable.AutoPk,MyTable.sensorName,MyTable.SensorValue,MyTable.SensorValue,MyTable.timest
FROM (SELECT
  MAX(timest8_) AS RegTime,
  sensorName8_
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY sensorName8_)
AS Result1
INNER JOIN MyTable
  ON Result1.RegTime = MyTable.timest8_
WHERE Result1.sensorName8_ = MyTable.sensorName8_
```

Selecting the Latest timest8_ with its sensor name, then inner joining the result set with MyTable. From the result set required columns can be selected.

Comment: I don't think that's going to find the last entry for each sensor

Comment: @Greg Foreach sensor! I didn't notice

Comment: That'll give you the latest time, but not the value of the sensor

Comment: @Greg Any prob with this one? Any way the OP is not responding :-)

Comment: that one looks right :).

Comment: Thank you so much it's working. o/p is as i expected . But o/p is coming with extra column RegTime. My table name is sensor_log_history. I want to execute this query using hibernate. Is it work ?

Comment: this will work I think. I'm not familiar with hibernate. Please give a try.

Comment: Then how to avoid that RegTime in result ?

Comment: select only the required columns instead of selecting *

Comment: Thank you so much subin jacob :) it's working and ur help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @sagarreddy Then chose it as your best answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the tablename, so assume its TableName, and Name the one you want to find, this should return the latest record with that name.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE sensorName = 'Name' ORDER BY timest DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You should be able to do it in 1 query, not have to query for each sensor

Comment: yes what greg said is correct i want to use only one query. I want  to use this query in hibernate